# jQuery Validation: how to implement a more friendly error message alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Like SO's question or answer form alert message: **`Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 3.`**, the last number display the current amount of characters. For that I think that I need calculate the number and append the error message, and I can append the number to the `errorPlacement`'s first parameter `error` like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/sscs1kbx/5/

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  var placement = $(element).data('error');
  if (placement) {
     error.append(CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData().replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '').length);
    $(placement).append(error)
  } else {
    error.insertAfter(element);
  }
}
```

I works fine when user click submit button first time, but `errorPlacement` is called only once at the first time submitting, so, after that, I works failed?  which method or function should I use for this goal? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please do not tag-spam.  The jQuery Validation Engine and the jQuery Validate plugin are not the same thing.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a dynamic error message in your `addMethod("minlengthxo",...)`:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("minlengthxo", function (value, element, param) {
    debugger
    originalVal = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData().replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
    var length = $.isArray(originalVal) ? value.length : this.getLength(originalVal, element);
    return length >= param;
}, function (params, element) {
    enteredLength = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData().replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '').length;
    return 'You need input at least 18 characters, now you entered ' + enteredLength
});
```

Here is a [live exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/k82f1wah/)

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I have be looking for! I tried this: `var errMsg = function() {...};` and used this  as the third parameter, `jQuery.validator.addMethod("minlengthxo", function(){}, errMsg)`, but it failed, I don't know why? Here, defining a anonymous function is must?

Comment: Thanks , what's the difference between your way and mine?  This must be a javascript syntax question, sorry

Comment: This is a good question which you can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also found this question.